# How do I close javascript popup box after validation is successful with php ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my html form, a popup window appears for registration. It validates data with an ajax/query call with `regProcess.php` page. This page is passing data to html form with `json_encode`. Well, when all validation is successful I want to close the html popup box after few second. How can I do this?

```javascript
<script>
  $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'backup.php',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',       

      success: function (data) {
        $('#info1').html('');
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
          $('#info1').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');               
        });    

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The popup window appears with following div call.

```html
<div id="register">
  <a class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal">
    <button type="button" name="" value="" class="css3button">Join the campaign</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code for popup box? Or what is ID or classname?

Comment: @Dikesh `<div id="register"><a class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal"><button type="button" 
name="" value="" class="css3button">Join the campaign</button></a></div>` this is a button. when I click on it. it appear a popup box.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a jquery function in the **success function** with the **setTimeout()**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: @lago Melanias It's not working....I want when there is no error it's saying "Successfully registered" on the html form. After 3 second it's should close the popup box. how can i do this ?

Comment: You can see this example: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/mcapi-simple-subscribe-jquery.zip

This form has a jquery function with ajax validation. When the form is sent, a message is showed and you can hide the popup only adding a new function to the `sucess: function`.